# Building my own script for gasoline pump effect

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write my own Script, because i have not found Jquery plugin suitable to my case.
I basically need to write a script which gives a Cash register or Gasoline Pump effect to my numbers loading automatically Thousand separator '.' and decimal separator ',' in my numbers, like exactly in this [example](http://jsbin.com/ehuzes/19/edit) 
The Only difference from the example is that i want my numbers automatically load in the page without clicking on the botton

Is it possible to modify this script and making work without the function on click?

Alternatively how would you set up the script giving the function for thousand separator and decimal separator?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

well easiest way is to copy the javascript in that example and put it into its own .js file.

call mootools library script from your html `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.2.4/mootools-yui-compressed.js"></script>`

then call your plugin file `<script src="js/plugin.js"></script>`

then include your initialization script (from that example, it looks like it goes at the bottom of the page, but im not sure)

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    //<![CDATA[
      window.addEvent('domready', function(){
        var total = $('total'); // this is the id of the element that will display the number
        var totalFx = new Fx.CashRegister(total, {duration: 2000});
        totalFx.start(124353526.99); // this is the number that you want to show first when page loads
        });
</script>
```

[see this jsBin i edited](http://jsbin.com/ehuzes/20/edit)

Comment: Cool, You hit the spot, i am trying to see the changes you mentioned but i dont see in the JSBin you linked

Comment: i simplified the html a bit more in this [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/ehuzes/22/edit) all i really changed was the initialization script above the `</body>` tag the script copying and including to the DOM of your html is all on you